# selenium's find element by xpath getting error where same expression in lxml is ok

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, lxml

I have faced this problem for various xpath expressions. The `find_element_by_xpath()` method of selenium fails whereas lxml for the same expression gives the expected value. For example:

```
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(br.page_source).xpath('//a[@title="2"]/text()')
... ['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t2\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t2\n\t\t\t\t\t']

>>> br.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="2"]/text()')
... InvalidSelectorException: Message: {"errorMessage":"The result of the xpath expression \"//a[@title=\"2\"]/text()\" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"108","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:47455","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"85546b60-7c8e-11e4-b2ba-2bb5fbee7719\", \"value\": \"//a[@title=\\\"2\\\"]/text()\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/85546b60-7c8e-11e4-b2ba-2bb5fbee7719/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states - an xpath used inside [`find_element_by_xpath()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) **has to point to an element**. In your case, it *points to a text node*.

If you want to get the element's text, find the element first and then get the `.text`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="2"]')
print element.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add something, if the result is not one element, it is in a list.

```
    content = driver.find_element_by_id("aaa")
    all_children_by_xpath = content.find_elements_by_xpath("//p")
    for item in all_children_by_xpath:
        print item.text
```